# Time span accumulating fact tables design

Tags: data-warehouse, star-schema, fact-table

I need to design a star schema to process order processing. The progress of an order look like this:

- Customer C place an order on item I with quantity 100
- Factory F1 take the order partially with quantity 30
- Factory F2 take the order partially with quantity 20
- Buy from market 50 items
- F1 delivery 20 items
- F1 delivery 7 items
- F1 cancel the contract (we need to buy 3 more item from market)
- F2 delivery 20 items
- Buy from market 3 items
- Complete the order

How can I design a fact table in this case, since the number of step is not fixed, the data types of event is not the same.

I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: can we make it clear either you need to design a whole star schema or just a fact table. Because, the scenario you have mentioned - the whole star schema can be designed for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of an Accumulating Snapshot Fact table according to Kimball is:
summarizes the measurement events occurring at **predictable** steps between the beginning and the end of a process.

For this particular use case I would go with a **Transaction Fact Table** as the events (steps) are unpredictable, it is more like an event fact table, something similar to logs or audits.

```
| order_key | date_key | full_datetime       | entity_key (customer, factory, etc. varchar) | entity_type | state    | quantity |
|-----------|----------|---------------------|----------------------------------------------|-------------|----------|----------|
| 1         | 20190602 | 2019-06-02 04:30:00 | C1                                           | customer    | request  | 100      |
| 1         | 20190602 | 2019-06-02 05:30:00 | F1                                           | factory     | receive  | 30       |
| 1         | 20190602 | 2019-06-02 05:30:00 | F2                                           | factory     | receive  | 20       |
| 1         | 20190602 | 2019-06-02 05:40:00 | Company?                                     | company     | buy      | 50       |
| 1         | 20190603 | 2019-06-03 06:40:00 | F1                                           | factory     | deliver  | 20       |
| 1         | 20190603 | 2019-06-03 02:40:00 | F1                                           | factory     | deliver  | 7        |
| 1         | 20190603 | 2019-06-03 04:40:00 | F1                                           | factory     | deliver  | 3        |
| 1         | 20190603 | 2019-06-03 06:40:00 | F1                                           | factory     | cancel   |          |
| 1         | 20190604 | 2019-06-04 07:40:00 | F2                                           | factory     | deliver  | 20       |
| 1         | 20190604 | 2019-06-04 07:40:00 | Company?                                     | company     | buy      | 3        |
| 1         | 20190604 | 2019-06-04 09:40:00 | Company?                                     | company     | complete | 100      |
```

I'm not sure about your reporting needs as they were not specified, but assuming you need to measure lag/durations of unpredictable steps, you could PIVOT and use dynamic SQL to create the required **view**

[SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Let me know if you came up with something different as I'm interested on this particular use case. Good luck